# How to make SVN automatically commit the new created files?

Tags: svn

I have a PHP project which I need modify it a lot and add/delete files ocassionly. The problem is that I'll need to type the 'svn add/delete' command by hand for every new created/deleted file.

Is there any other easy way to handle this task?

Thanks.

Comment: You could switch to git, since "git add ." will recursively add all new files. But I'm just being an ass because I know you're not going to switch to git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy solved it on the command line using the following bash script:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  svn status | perl -ne 's/^\?\s+(\S.+)$/\1/g;chomp;system("svn add \"$_\"");'
```

http://www.amiryan.org/2009/04/22/howto-recursively-add-unversioned-files-into-svn-repository/

I use Subclipse through Eclipse.  Whenever I add files and commit the project, the files are automatically added.  One possible suggestion is to try Eclipse with Subclipse.